# What is @ in /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/java @/tmp/cp...... com.hoge.Application?

Tags: java, shell, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I am not sure this question is related to `/usr/bin/env` or `java` ..w/e shell?

What does the part `@/path` mean?

What does `@` mean?

`/usr/bin/env /path/to/java .... @/tmp/....`
It appears when I launch an Application in VScode.

Comment: have you looked at the command line options of `java`

Comment: can you enlighten us with the meaning of `@`? by text or a link

Comment: I wonder it stands for ```argument file```.. thank you I looked at the options list of Java

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running a maven project with VSCode. The '@' is a mechanism of java command line. You can see the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-source-file-mode-to-launch-single-file-source-code-programs). The '@' follows by a file path, and java will use the file content as argument. You can check the content of `/tmp/....` file. It's probably like `-cp ...`. The argument is too long, so VSCode generated a temp file to run java.